# can we get recent news from wall street journal and show it in asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Any api's available or any reference documents??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make an HTTP request to one of the various [RSS feeds](http://feeds2.feedburner.com/wsj/xml/rss/3_7480.xml) on their site, parse the XML and include accreditation and links back to the original stories.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to pick up [one of their RSS feeds](http://feeds.wsjonline.com/wsj/xml/rss/3_7011.xml), and parse it with some [RSS reader](http://rss-net.sourceforge.net/) library.